# MOSFET Current Source

Tags: mosfet, analog, circuit-design, current-source, homework

Implement a current source, with cascode topology, using Diodes Inc's 2N7002K MOSFET, satisfying the following requirements:

1. Use a voltage source of 5.5 Volts
2. \$ i_{out} = 6 ~ \mu A\$
3. \$ V_{out_{min}} < 2.5 V \$
4. \$ R_{out} > 0.7~G\Omega \$

Asume that the n-MOSFET has a \$\lambda= 104~\mu V^{-1}\$

---

My attempt:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fi6IqV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[Here](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2010.20027730826997%2080%205%2050%0Ar%20224%20160%20224%20192%200%2076878.4%0Af%20272%20336%20224%20336%2016%202.5%200.032%0Af%20272%20240%20224%20240%2016%202.5%200.032%0Aw%20224%20288%20224%20256%201%0Aw%20224%20288%20224%20320%202%0Aw%20224%20192%20224%20224%202%0Aw%20224%20192%20272%20192%200%0Aw%20272%20192%20272%20240%200%0Aw%20224%20288%20272%20288%200%0Aw%20272%20288%20272%20336%200%0Aw%20272%20336%20304%20336%201%0Af%20304%20336%20352%20336%2016%202.5%200.032%0Af%20304%20240%20352%20240%2016%202.5%200.032%0Aw%20304%20240%20272%20240%201%0Aw%20352%20256%20352%20320%201%0Ag%20352%20384%20352%20400%200%0Aw%20352%20368%20352%20352%200%0Ar%20448%20144%20448%20208%200%20150000%0Aw%20224%20128%20352%20128%201%0Aw%20352%20128%20352%20144%203%0Aw%20352%20208%20352%20224%203%0Aw%20224%20160%20224%20128%201%0Aw%20352%20144%20448%20144%200%0Aw%20352%20208%20448%20208%200%0Aw%20352%20368%20352%20384%200%0Aw%20352%20384%20224%20384%200%0Aw%20224%20384%20224%20352%200%0Av%20160%20192%20160%20128%200%200%2040%205.5%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20160%20192%20160%20384%200%0Aw%20160%20384%20224%20384%200%0Aw%20224%20128%20160%20128%200%0Ar%20224%20224%20224%20256%200%201600000000%0Ar%20224%20320%20224%20352%200%201600000000%0Ar%20352%20320%20352%20352%200%201600000000%0Ar%20352%20224%20352%20256%200%201600000000%0A) you can see the simulation (using an arbitrary \$150k\Omega\$ load), and the output current works fine. My concern is with the output impedance.

**My question is how to compute the output impedance of this n-MOSFET current source?**

I'm not sure if in this case I can use the (known) small-signal output impedance formula of a cascode configuration wich, according to Sedra-Smith, is \$ r_{out} \approx g_{m} r_{o_1}r_{o_2}\$, where \$r_{o_1}=r_{o_2}=r_o=\frac{1}{\lambda I_D} = \frac{1}{106\mu V^{-1}\times 6\mu A} = 1.6~G\Omega \$

My guess is that I can not use this formula, because my current source is a DC source (\$ \neq \$small signal) while this formula was deduced from the small-signal model.

Comment: Output impedance is a small signal parameter - it is the slope of the output.

Comment: *My guess is that I can not use this formula* Well, you can, **at a certain point of operation** the circuit behaves as an ideal current source (at the DC value of 6uA) in parallel with a resistor of 1.6 Gohm. That 1.6 Gohm is indeed the **slope** of the output voltage/current in the part where the current is nearly constant.